# Javascript Regular Expression Match

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str=">1 people>9 people>1u people";
    document.write(str.match(/>.*people/img).length);
</script>
```

at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_dot.
This code should return an array of size **3** but it return array of size **1**.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.*` part of your regexp is being "greedy" and taking as many characters as it can, in this case returning the entire string as a single match.

Write it like this instead, with a trailing `?`:

```
str.match(/>.*?people/img)
```

See the section describing "?" in the [Mozilla Developer Network JS Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).